# iOS custom scrollbar for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uislider

iOS scrollbars for a `UIScrollView` usually hide after a brief delay, but I want to the scrollbars in my app to show all the time like in this picture: [image: Scrollbars visible all the time]

Do you have any Idea how to implement this feature? Can I use a custom UISlider for this? If you can provide answers, please do so in simple English because it's not my native language. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way to show scrollbar  permanent.

**You can do this by UISlider and UIImageView.**

**1) Add UImage View for Vertical line.**

```
UIImageView *scrollLineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scroll_1-1.png"]];
scrollLineImageView.frame = CGRectMake(970,160,2,254);
[self.view addSubview:scrollLineImageView];
```

**2) Add UISlider and transform to  UISlider vertical .UISlider  height should be your scroll view height.**

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
self.scrollViewSlider.transform = trans;
self.scrollViewSlider.frame = CGRectMake(972.5,189,0, self.textScrollView.frame.size.height);
Set Slider minimum value to 0 and maximum value to scrollView content height.
self.scrollViewSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
self.scrollViewSlider.maximumValue = self.textScrollView.contentSize.height;
```

**3) Set UISlider Thumb Image**

```
[self.scrollViewSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scroll_circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**4) Clear Minimum and Maximum track Image.**

```
UIImage *clearImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[self.scrollViewSlider setMinimumTrackImage:clearImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.scrollViewSlider setMaximumTrackImage:clearImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**5) ScrollView Delegate Function to scroll slider**

```
self.scrollViewSlider.value=scrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

I hope this helps you to show Scroll Bar Permanent.